# Display Rich Text Content as UIWebView or UILabel+CoreText

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, core-text

I'd like to display rich text content in my app. I want user to create simple WYSIWYG input with support of bold, italics, shadow, outline, image HTML-like tags. I am puzzled if I should go with UIWebView or custom written UILabel/UIView which can have CoreText framework added to support all those above stated properties. I see there are libraries which are using both approaches.

Does anyone have an experience dealing with these approaches who can suggest cons and pros? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web view approach has quite an overhead and likely a delay to display the rendered text. I would recommend using [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText).

Comment: Wasn't aware of how far along this is, looks like a great option. Good answer.